# Python : error during installation of future module

Tags: python, future

Here is my configuration : Windows 7 64 bits, Python 3.5.3 64 bits

I am trying to install future-0.16.0.tar.gz via the setup file (can't use pip because I am not connected to the Internet), and I get this error :

*...byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\libfuturize\fixes\fix_add__future__imports_except_unicode_literals.py to fix_add__future__imports_except_unicode_literals.cpython-35.pyc

**error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\libfuturize\fixes\__pycache__\fix_add__future__imports_except_unicode_literals.cpython-35.pyc.69344256'***

Just to check, I have tried to install the future module with Python 3.5.3 32 bits and have encountered any problem at all.
But for a problem of Oracle client, I can't use the win32 version...
So I am stuck...

Does someone have an idea of where this comes from?

Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to say hello... So HELLO TO EVERYONE! I've tried to edit my post, but the changes never appear.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the team that works on future, I had my answer.

The problem was I reached the MAX_PATH (The maximum character length of a path) of Windows. That "simple"!

So I copied the source files locally, and installed them. Problem solved.

Python was not guilty! And the work can go on...

Here's an article on how to enable paths > 260 chars: [How to Make Windows 10 Accept File Paths Over 260 Characters](https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/)

Comment: Thank you so much! This workaround successfully worked for me too. The issue gave me so much headache...